# How to provide scrollPane to JFXPANEL without having any scene in it?

Tags: javafx-2

I have to convert Swing JPanel to JavaFX JFXPanel.
That JPanel has no component in it. It is simply get painted when UI gets rendered. That JPanel has only JScrollPane.

Now we know that JScrollPane can be created by below statement. Where we have to pass the Component in which we want the scroll pane to be added.

```
JScrollPane sp= new JScrollPane(Component view);
```

Now in JAVAFX Scroll Pane does not have direct method like above. It has only

```
ScrollPane js = new ScrollPane();
js.setContent(Node n);
```

The above statment will add the scroll pane to the Node given as a parameter.

But in my case As I told earlier that I have 0 nodes in my JFXPanel. How do I set ScrollPane to this JFXPanel?

Comment: The javafx ScrollPane has a constructor which takes in a node as a parameter. [`public ScrollPane(Node content)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#ScrollPane-javafx.scene.Node-). The `setContent(node n)` adds node to scrollpane, not the vice-versa, as you have mentioned.

Comment: I am using javaFx 2.2. So not able to have that facility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "provide scrollPane to JFXPANEL without having any scene".

A [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) is a node which needs to be placed in a [JavaFX scene graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106328) for it to be useful.  A scene graph requires a [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).